# Gauss-Seidel Method of a Linear System Ax=b with the MATLAB parallel toolbox

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I´m trying modifying the Gauss-Seidel method in MATLAB to be able to execute my Linear System Ax=b in parallel over the workers. I change both Nested for loops into parfor loops (because there are not dependencies). First, I implement the same problem that MATLAB provide as a Gauss-Seidel method to see if it gives the same values. It was working either in Serial and in Parallel. Later on I tried to do the same for an A(1000,1000) Matrix with an Array of b(1000,1) but the results that I get using the same code was not the same and the execution time in parallel was much more bigger than running it in serial. Do I change the Serial code into a parallel correct ? Would somebody of you suggest a more sufficient solution ?

```
A=[5 -2 3 0 6; -3 9 1 -2 7.4; 2 -1 -7 1 6.7; 4 3 -5 7 9; 2 3.5 6.1 -4 -8.1];
b=[-1 2 3 0.5 3.1]' ;
x=rand(5,1);

n=size(x,1);
normVal=inf;
tol=1e-3; 
GaussItr=0;

plotGauss=[];
timeStart = tic;
while normVal>tol

   x_old = x ;

   for i=1:n
       sigma = 0;

       parfor j=1:i-1
           sigma = sigma+A(i,j)*x(j);
       end

       parfor j=i+1:n
           sigma = sigma +A(i,j)*x_old(j);
       end

       x(i)=(1/A(i,i))*(b(i)-sigma);

   end

   GaussItr=GaussItr+1;
   normVal=norm(x_old-x);
   plotGauss=[plotGauss;normVal];

end
timeEnd = toc(timeStart);
```

Comment: Please post also your working serial Gauss-Seidel implementation so that we can quickly compare.

Comment: Is the same like the above but instead of parfor I am using simple for.

Answer (score 0):

1. i and j are defined by default as complex numbers so it is better to use ii and jj.
2. matlab gives warning messages + examples how to fix them so you can use it to fix your code.

On you code you will get warnings on:

- `plotGauss` increases size on each iteration:

  `plotGauss=[plotGauss;normVal];`

  Solution: replace while loop with for loop, giving reasonable number of iterations, preinitialize plotGauss array and break the for loop when normVal(ii)<=tol
- `sigma` is passed between iterations so you don't make it parallel:

```
    parfor j=1:i-1
       sigma = sigma+A(i,j)*x(j);
    end
```

Solution: calculate multiplications in parfor saving results in temporary array and then 
 sum after the loop.

```
tmp = zeros(1,n);
...
    parfor jj=1:ii-1
       tmp(jj)= A(ii,jj)*x(jj);
    end
    sigma = sum(tmp(1:ii-1));
```

in summary:

untested (sorry, I don't have matlab at home)

```
MAX_ITER = 100;

A=[5 -2 3 0 6; -3 9 1 -2 7.4; 2 -1 -7 1 6.7; 4 3 -5 7 9; 2 3.5 6.1 -4 -8.1];
b=[-1 2 3 0.5 3.1]' ;
x=rand(5,1);

n=size(x,1);
normVal=inf;
tol=1e-3; 
% GaussItr=0; => see below for loop

sigma = 0;
tmp = zeros(1,n);

plotGauss=nan*ones(1,MAX_ITER);
timeStart = tic;
for kk=1:MAX_ITER

    x_old = x ;

    for ii=1:n

        parfor jj=1:ii-1
            tmp(jj)= A(ii,jj)*x(jj);
        end

        tmp(ii) = 0; % to keep sigma as sum of all tmp elements

        parfor jj=ii+1:n
            tmp(jj)= A(ii,jj)*x_old(jk);
        end

        sigma = sum(tmp);

        x(ii)=(1/A(ii,ii))*(b(ii)-sigma);

    end

    % GaussItr=GaussItr+1; => use kk index instead
    normVal=norm(x_old-x);
    plotGauss(kk) = normVal;

    if normVal<=tol
        break; % break the for loop if we already reached desire tolerance
    end

end
timeEnd = toc(timeStart);

GaussItr = kk;

if normVal>tol
   error('code finished after %d iterations without reaching desired tolerance',GaussItr);
end
```

Comment: First of all thank you a lot @AlBaZ. I run it in MATLAB and for this small Matrix it is working. But after, I import a bigger Matrix A[1000x1000]and it is not working! The Serial execution of the same problem 1000x1000 needs ~10sec while the parallel execution doesn´t work... Do you have any suggestion why this happens ?